# Keyboard plugged in display cannot be used until monitor wake-up message disappears

Tags: display, external-display, wake-up, dell-precision, input-device

I have a Dell UltraSharp 49" (U4919DW) display and I use it as an input to connect all my devices (keyboard, mouse, headphones, etc.) and connect to my laptop (Dell Precision 5560) through USB-C. I experience this problem where when the monitor goes in Stand-By Mode, after I have been away from my PC for some time (laptop goes to sleep), I can wake it up using the keyboard, but I cannot type/use the keyboard until the monitor loading message disappears (Semi transparent Dell message rectangle in the middle of the screen describing the input sources that stays on the screen for roughly 1-2 seconds).
Is this standard functionality that cannot be disabled?
If yes, what baffles me is that I can wake up both the laptop and the display using the keyboard, but I cannot type until the message disappears.

I tried different settings on my laptop (Settings->Devices->USB), and I couldn't find a setting on my monitor for USB power/devices.

Comment: Things to test.  1. If laptop is plugged into the monitor it is charging.  No need to go to standby.   Check laptop power saving is not putting laptop to standby.  Only turen off screen (if on).  May eliminate laptop as possible source of problem (historically lots of standby+ USB glitches). 2. Check monitor settings to check that Auto KVM is turned OFF.  That might create a delay, especially if laptop is resuming. https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics_accessories/esuprt_electronics_accessories_monitors/dell-u4919dw-monitor_user's-guide_en-us.pdf (p71)

Comment: 3. Some users had USB-C cable related issues resolved by upgrading Dell supplied cable: https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/U4919DW-KVM-USB-hub-device-disconnect-issues/m-p/7719468#M130016 (I suspect my comments #1 and #2 are more likely the issue but... (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01L0F6AJI)